# Why is this javascript function executing more times per second than it's supposed to

Tags: javascript, function, math, dom

I am working on a sort of clicker game where the user is able to buy upgrades. One such upgrade involves the user earning a certain amount of in-game currency per second, in this case 0.1. Unfortunately if the user decides to buy more than one of this upgrade it appears to rise exponentially. I feel like this might be because the setInterval() function is stacking each time, so that the first time it is 0.1 then the next its 0.1 + 0.2 so 0.3, then 0.3 + 0.2 + 0.1 so 0.6 and so on.

```
upgradePerSec1.onclick = function() {
  if (presents >= cost1) {
    presents -= cost1;
    upgrade1Amount += 1;
    totalPresentsSpent += cost1;
    cost1 = Math.ceil(cost1Base *= 1.03 ** upgrade1Amount);
    perSec += 0.1;
    displayScore.innerHTML = format(presents) + " Presents delivered.";
    cost1Disp.innerHTML = "<hr>Cost: " + format(cost1);
    title.innerHTML = format(presents) + " Presents";
    perSecDisp.innerHTML = formatPerSec(perSec) + " presents /s";
    totalPresentsSpentDisp.innerHTML = format(totalPresentsSpent) + " Total presents spent";
    setInterval(increment1, 1000);
  } else {
    alert("You don't have enough presents! Still need: " + format(cost1 - presents));
  }
}

function increment1() {
  presents += perSec;
  totalPresents += perSec;
  displayScore.innerHTML = format(presents) + " Presents delivered.";
  totalPresentsDisp.innerHTML = format(totalPresents) + " Total presents delivered";
  title.innerHTML = format(presents) + " Presents";
}
```

Here is some clarification for this code:

- `upgradePerSec1` = HTML button element
- `cost1` = the cost of this upgrade
- `perSec` = variable to store the amount of "presents" per second
- `displayScore` = an HTML label element
- `cost1Disp` = an HTML label element
- `title` = the browser tab title
- `format()` = a function to format large numbers by adding in commas
- `totalPresents` = the total presents without taking away costs (used for a statistics section)

I have tried replacing the `perSec` variable with just the number(obviously did not work) I have tried making the timing also rise but could not get the correct timing. Ive also searched many places on the web and could not find any helpful results. I saw one on stack overlfow but it did not apply to me.

Comment: Every time you click on thebutton, you start running `increment1` every second. You never stop the previous one if you click multiple times. You should check if they've already clicked on it.

Comment: @Barmar How would I go about stopping the previous one? As far as I know there is no stop function for the setInterval function

Comment: There is [`clearInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/clearInterval).

Comment: You don't need to stop the old one. Just don't start a new one.

Comment: @Barmar Thank you I will implement this now. Just realised you posted an answer with this fix. Thanks.

Comment: Not me, someone else posted that.

Comment: You're right overlooked that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, the `setInterval` calls are stacking. To fix the issue, you should make sure you only call `setInterval()` once (e.g. by adding an if statement before that line checking if `perSec === 0`).

e.g.

```
upgradePerSec1.onclick = function() {
  if (presents >= cost1) {
    if (perSec === 0) {
      setInterval(increment1, 1000);
    }
    presents -= cost1;
    upgrade1Amount += 1;
    totalPresentsSpent += cost1;
    cost1 = Math.ceil(cost1Base *= 1.03 ** upgrade1Amount);
    perSec += 0.1;
    displayScore.innerHTML = format(presents) + " Presents delivered.";
    cost1Disp.innerHTML = "<hr>Cost: " + format(cost1);
    title.innerHTML = format(presents) + " Presents";
    perSecDisp.innerHTML = formatPerSec(perSec) + " presents /s";
    totalPresentsSpentDisp.innerHTML = format(totalPresentsSpent) + " Total presents spent";
  } else {
    alert("You don't have enough presents! Still need: " + format(cost1 - presents));
  }
}

function increment1() {
  presents += perSec;
  totalPresents += perSec;
  displayScore.innerHTML = format(presents) + " Presents delivered.";
  totalPresentsDisp.innerHTML = format(totalPresents) + " Total presents delivered";
  title.innerHTML = format(presents) + " Presents";
}
```

Comment: yea...trying using async await, and await a 'delay' function call

Comment: This would not work for me as `setInterval()` is only meant to run after the the upgrade has been purchased

Comment: I've long ago learned that just describing the change is not enough, the OP never gets it. You need to post the updated code.

Comment: I have just tried running the game with this code and it does not do anything for some reason. Everytime `upgradePerSec1` is clicked it takes away the cost from the presents but doesnt actually increment the presents.

Comment: Sorry, that was me being an idiot. The if statement should go before the increment of perSec. Try the new code and let me know if it works!

Comment: No worries! It works fully now thank you so much for this.

Comment: @Livebughelp-www.dialect.so I have tried this solution now with more than one upgrade unfortunately after testing it the stacking problem persists.